# Error with simple stitching and OpenCV 3.2.0 - cv2.cpp:152: error: (-215) The data should normally be NULL! in function NumpyAllocator::allocate

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to use OpenCV to stitch images, but even for the simplest code I get error `cv2.cpp:152: error: (-215) The data should normally be NULL! in function NumpyAllocator::allocate`

I have it tested on Mac with python 2.7.10 and on Windows with python 3.6.1

The code looks like below:

```
import cv2

cv2.ocl.setUseOpenCL(False)
stitcher = cv2.createStitcher(False)
foo = cv2.imread("image1.jpg")
bar = cv2.imread("image2.jpg")
result = stitcher.stitch((foo,bar))
```

Based on google search some people suggest that `cv2.ocl.setUseOpenCL(False)` fixes this problem, but apparently it doesn't in my case :)

Any suggestions how to make it work are appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Edit - August 15th, 2018

This issue is now fixed as of OpenCV 3.3.  If you haven't already, please upgrade to at least this version.  See the comment at the end of the issue page regarding this: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/6969.

I'll leave the previous answer below for those who aren't using OpenCV 3.3 and above.

---

This unfortunately is a bug in OpenCV 3.x that has not been fixed yet.  Here's a link to the issues page on Github: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/6969

On the page, one way to hack this would be to actually open up the `modules/python/src2/cv2.cpp` source file and to remove the `if` statement around line 152 in that error.  That `if` statement is:

```
    if( data != 0 )
    {
        CV_Error(Error::StsAssert, "The data should normally be NULL!");
        // probably this is safe to do in such extreme case
        return stdAllocator->allocate(dims0, sizes, type, data, step, flags, usageFlags);
    }
```

There was one person on the issues page that removed this entire `if` statement, then recompiled OpenCV and this finally worked.  This is unfortunately the only known way around this, even with OpenCL being disabled.

Note that this error only exists in the Python interface as the exception is being thrown in the source file that interacts between the Python and C++ environments (i.e. the `cv2.cpp` file). You can definitely get the stitcher working in the native C++ API without this exception being thrown.

Comment: Thank you, do you happen to know if this problem is also showing up when using OpenCV 3.* with C++?

Comment: Just python. The file that the exception is being thrown in is the interface file between the python and C++ environments. You can definitely get the stitcher working in C++.

Comment: No problem! Good luck.